# Applying different shaders to meshes

Tags: javascript, three.js, post-processing

I have meshes, which applied video texture. I want to apply different shaders on those meshes (for example, monochrome and sepia). Now I can see only one of them. In this example only second (2). If I comment (2), I will see (1). How I can see both?

```
  onRenderFcts.push(function(delta, now) {
    composer.render(delta); //(1)
    composerGray.render(delta); //(2)
  })
```

[Project on github](https://github.com/MorningCappuccino/videoShaders)

## Photo example:

[link to photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkHw2.jpg)

Comment: Of course, I have 2 scenes. First scene for sepia filter, second - for monochrome. I think it's not a good decision (what if I want 10 filters - 10 scenes?). May be exist better decision of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Now I have been using standard postprocessing and shaders things. Without extention THREEx.js and strange for me blocks of code.

**Result (image):**
[see what I've done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzm9r.jpg)

**Link to project:** [github](https://github.com/MorningCappuccino/videoShaders2)